# Maven groovy-eclipse-compiler with error-prone

Tags: maven, compiler-construction

is it possible to use groovy-eclipse-compiler with error-prone (https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/)?

groovy-eclipse-plugin requires this config in pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

error-prone:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerId>javac-with-errorprone</compilerId>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
```

so they both set `<compilerId>`. Is there any way to use 2 compilers together? I know Lombok can be used in such scenario as agent, but I don't think error-prone has one.

Thanks in advance,
Michal